linear vector addition in norm of vectors suggest a line segment in the unit circle
Let $V$ be a normed vector space, which contains two linearlly-independant vectors $x,y$ such that $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$. Prove that the unit circle $\{x \in V:\|x\|=1\}$ contains a line segment.
From playing around with the norm $\|x\|=\max\{x_1,x_2\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$,I thought about taking my line segments between $u=\frac{x}{\|x\|},v=\frac{y}{\|y\|}$. It's trivial to show that every point on the line segment has a norm less than 1: $\|tu+(1-t)v\|\leq t\|u\|+(1-t)\|v\|=1$.
I'm having trouble proving that this inequality is an equality.
I also proved that $\frac{x+y}{\|x+y\|}$ is in the line segment and has a unit norm.
I tried to assume there's a point on the line segment that has a norm strictly less than 1, but I didn't managed to get a contradiction.

Use that $| x+y| = |x | + | y|$ and $|u|=|v|=1$ to arrive at $t+1-t=1$.

but $t+1-t=1$ is true regardless of the assumptions

That's right, $t+1-t=1$ which will show that the point on the segment between $u$ and $v$ is on the unit circle. You have written the main idea with the inequality already, replace it with an equality since it's given that $| x+y| = |x | + | y|$ and using that $| tu |= t |u|$. since $t \geq 0$.

$|x+y|=|x|+|y|$ doesn't imply $|ax+by|=a|x|+b|y|$ for any two scalars $a,b$

It's true for any norm that $|tu| = |t||u|$. Since $t \geq 0$ you do have $|tu| = t|u|$.

@CyclotomicField It seems to me as well that all your arguments do not show that every point on the segment between $u$
and $v$
is on the unit circle.

Wlog, $V=\operatorname{span}(x,y)=\Bbb R^2$, but the norm is not necessarily $\|x\|=\max\{x_1,x_2\}$ (anyway, you didn't use that assumption).
You were on the right track. Let $a:=\|x\|\ne0$, $b:=\|y\|\ne0$, $u=\frac xa$, $v:=\frac yb$, $w_t:=tu+(1-t)v$, and $\alpha:=\frac a{a+b}$. You already observed that
$$\forall t\in[0,1]\quad\|w_t\|\le1$$
and
$$\|w_\alpha\|=\left\|\frac{au+bv}{a+b}\right\|=\frac{\|x+y\|}{\|x\|+\|y\|}=1.
$$
Assume that $\|w_t\|<1$ for some $t\in[0,1]$. Wlog, $t>\alpha$, and then, $w_\alpha=sw_t+(1-s)v$ for $s=\frac\alpha t\in(0,1]$.
$$1=\|w_\alpha\|\le s\|w_t\|+(1-s)\|v\|=1-s(1-\|w_t\|)<1.$$
This contradiction proves that
$$\forall t\in[0,1]\quad\|w_t\|=1.$$
